# Monero daemon causes 100% disk utilization on Windows with new wallet install.

Tags: monerod, windows

I am getting started with monero.  I installed the wallet on my windows 10 laptop.  it appears to be very slowly downloading the blockchain.  However monerod causes my disk utilization to max out at 100% and my laptop is unusable.  I don't mind downloading for a few days in the background, but is there some way to prevent the 100% disk utilization?  I am not using an SSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While syncing the blockchain, the Monero daemon generates a lot of disk IO calls to create its database, and HDDs are pretty slow at that compared to SSDs.

I'm not sure if there's a reliable way to limit the disk IO rate per process on Windows, but you could try to open the *Task Manager* and set the priority of the *monerod* process to "Low". It might improve the usability of the other applications running with a "Normal" priority.

Comment: Using Windows Process Explorer (not Task Manager) I was able to set the priority of monerod to "background".  After the change the disk utilization in reported in Task Manager is still around 100%, but other applications are more responsive.